# Fill array with existing objects

Tags: java

I have one maybe rather silly questions.
I have 3 Paint objects - Paint1, Paint2, Paint3. For readability those are declares separately. All 3 of the have few different attributes and one common - the color.

Is there a way to fill them inside some sort of collection and set the color attribute with for loop?

For an example:

```
Paint paint1, paint2; paint3;

paint1=new Paint();
paint1.setTextSize(10dp);

paint2=new Paint();
paint2.setTextSize(20dp)

paint3=new Paint();
paint3.setTextSize(30dp)

Paint[] arrayOfPaints = {paint1,paint2,paint3};

for(int i = 0; i < arrayOfPaints.length; i++){
        arrayOfPaints[i].setColorFilter(color);
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with your example? It seems that you've answered your own question! :D

Comment: Oh someone asked something and answered it in the same  question.....That's something new

Comment: No, no - the problem is that I want to do that for already existing object. I already have Paint Paint1= new Paint(); and Paint Paint2=new Paint();

Comment: I still se nothing wrong with your `Paint[] arrayOfPaints = {paint1,paint2,paint3};`. You can do that no matter where the objects were declared or instantiated.

Comment: @OleV.V. he has edited the question to include the answer... edit fail

Comment: I was adding the paints to the list before they were initialized in my code. Solution was provided and selected - thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so this is the answer.

```
Paint paint1;
Paint paint2;
Paint paint3;

List<Paint> paints = new ArrayList<Paint>();
paints.add(paint1);
paints.add(paint2);
paints.add(paint3);

for(Paint paint : paints) {
paint.setColorFilter(color);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, though you don't need `i` in the loop, so can use an enhanced loop and `paints` is a better name, as it's usually better to not put the collection type implementation detail in the name of a variable:

```
List<Paint> paints = Arrays.asList(paint1, paint2, paint3);
for(Paint paint : paints) {
    paint.setColorFilter(color);
}
```

Comment: It is not about iterating through the array - it is about filling the array with Paint objects which already exist and are used outside the loop.

Comment: As they where declared separately, I think something like `List<Paint> paints = Arrays.asList(paint1, paint2, paint3);` is missing